# How to make sure all MPV windows always have a ipc connection? for command line control

Tags: windows, mpv

For some time now, I have been looking for a way to control specific MPV windows from the command line.

After searching and asking around, for example, [HERE](https://old.reddit.com/r/mpv/comments/14ll6s6/append_a_file_to_the_the_currently_set_of_files/) and [HERE](https://old.reddit.com/r/mpv/comments/14m54u5/contrlling_mpv_from_the_command_line_via_pipe/), I managed to find a way.

I first need to make sure I create this "ipc server" thing at the time of opening the video:

```
 mpv  "C:\temp\cat.mp4" "--input-ipc-server=\\.\pipe\mpy_win"
```

From then, I can send commands only to that specific window with:

```
'cycle pause' | Out-File -literalPath '\\.\pipe\mpy_win'
```

This gets me 80% there. The problem is that 90% of the I am creating MPV windows from a File Explorer window by double clicking on video files. So I cant create an "ipc server" right then.

I tried placing the `--input-ipc-server=` command in my **MPV.conf** file:

```
--input-ipc-server=\\.\pipe\mpv_${window-id}
```

I tried to solve the issue of the ipc server name not being unique per window, by appending the property [window-id](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#command-interface-window-id) to the server name. But it seems, you cannot use property expansion with this command.

I am out of ideas. Is there a better or perhaps a more conventional way to do this?

I am on windows 11 on the latest MPV

Any help would be greatly appreciated!